# How Do I Backup My PostgreSQL Database with Cron?

Tags: bash, postgresql, cron, backup

I can run commands like vacuumdb, pg_dump, and psql just fine in a script if I preface them like so:

```
/usr/bin/sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/pg_dump -Fc mydatabase > /opt/postgresql/prevac.gz
/usr/bin/sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/vacuumdb --analyze mydatabase
/usr/bin/sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/pg_dump -Fc mydatabase > /opt/postgresql/postvac.gz
SCHEMA_BACKUP="/opt/postgresql/$(date +%w).db.schema"
sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/pg_dump -C -s mydatabase > $SCHEMA_BACKUP
```

These run at command line on Redhat when I am sudo to root and then as you see in the commands above I do a sudo -u to postgres.

But when I try to kick this off from cron, **I get zero bytes in all the files -- meaning it didn't run properly.** And I don't get a clue in the logs that I can see.

My /etc/crontab file has this entry at the bottom

```
00 23 * * * root /etc/db_backup.cron
```

And yes, /etc/db_backup.cron is chmod ug+x, owned by root, and the top of the file says "#!/bin/bash" (minus doublequotes).

Anyone know what gives?

Comment: at least on redhat, % symbols needs to be escaped. not escaping it will result in cron trying to execute your command only up until the %. See - http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2009/05/percent-sign-in-crontab.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you seem to have superuser rights anyway, you could put those commands into the crontab of the postgres user like so:

```
sudo su postgres
crontab -e
```

and then put the pg_dump/vacuumdb commands there.

Comment: This is what I ultimately ended up doing and it worked fine only when I did chown postgres.root /opt/postgresql (where the files were going).

Comment: ''sudo su postgres'' That's crazy! Try ''sudo -u postgres''. Setup a sudo spec, it's much safer.

Comment: You (postgres) are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration.

Answer (score 17):

I have a dynamic bash script that backs up all the databases on the server. It gets a list of all the databases and then vacuums each DB before performing a backup. All logs are written to a file and then that log is emailed to me. This is something you could use if you want.

Copy the code below into a file and add the file to your crontab. I have setup my pg_hba.conf to trust local connections.

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile="/backup/pgsql.log"
backup_dir="/backup"
touch $logfile
databases=`psql -h localhost -U postgres -q -c "\l" | sed -n 4,/\eof/p | grep -v rows\) | grep -v template0 | grep -v template1 | awk {'print $1'}`

echo "Starting backup of databases " >> $logfile
for i in $databases; do
        dateinfo=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
        timeslot=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M'`
        /usr/bin/vacuumdb -z -h localhost -U postgres $i >/dev/null 2>&1
        /usr/bin/pg_dump -U postgres -i -F c -b $i -h 127.0.0.1 -f $backup_dir/$i-database-$timeslot.backup
        echo "Backup and Vacuum complete on $dateinfo for database: $i " >> $logfile
done
echo "Done backup of databases " >> $logfile

tail -15 /backup/pgsql.log | mailx youremail@domain.com
```

Comment: You can add '--analyze' to the /usr/bin/vacuumdb command to perform an analyze as well.

Comment: Here is another good script: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux

Comment: @Imraan Parker how do you manage to skip using the password? I want to backup as admin account of the database not the root user postgres how can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

I have set my cron like this. Every 59 minutes since monday to friday

```
*/59 * * * 1-5 sh /home/my_user/scripts/back_my_bd.sh
```

The script to run the backup is inside **back_my_bd.sh** file  and the content is:

```
pg_dump -U USERDATABASE DATABASENAME > /home/my_user/sql/mybackup.sql
```

And i created the .pgpass file inside home directory to allow the backup whithout specify the user and password

```
localhost:5432:DATABASENAME:USER:PASSWORD
```

Sorry my english is not good!

Answer (score 4):

Your environment variable are maybe not set in cron.

In your normal session, you probably have defined these variables:

```
PG_PORT
PG_HOST
PG_DATABASE
PG_USERNAME
PG_PASSWORD
```

Add an "env" into yout script.

Comment: I need a little more help than that I think. I put 'env' in there before the commands and after the #!/bin/bash and all it did was dump out the environment to the log file (because I'm now dumping the output to a logfile as it runs).

Comment: The way to set these variables would be
'export PG_PORT=5432' etc.

Comment: Those aren't exactly the variables used by pg_dump and vacuumdb. You can see the full list here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/libpq-envars.html

Comment: @bilitgates Nice!! Thank you. I've learned something today :-)

Answer (score 1):

you probably have "ident" authentication in your pg_hba.conf for your postgres user. 
The option  "-u postgres" fails when that is the case.
either change user to postgres in your backup script or configure a different authentication method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following command:
databases=`psql -h localhost -U postgres -q -c "\l" | sed -n 4,/\eof/p | grep -v rows\) | grep -v template0 | grep -v template1 | awk {'print $1'}`

You can use below:
databases=`psql -t -c "select datname from pg_database where datname not like 'template%';" | grep -v '^$'`

The first one return '|' for template databases and an empty line.

The second one is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

databases=`psql -h localhost -U postgres -q -x -t -c "\l" | grep 'Name' | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/Name|//g'`

Answer (score 0):

Another version to get the list of databases:
`psql -lqt | grep -vE '^ +(template[0-9]+|postgres)? *\|' | cut -d'|' -f1| sed -e 's/ //g' -e '/^$/d'`

As my `psql -lqt` output is:

```
 abcdefghij         | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres           | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0          | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                    |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1          | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                    |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 abc                | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```