# Is it possible to backup postgres for data for specific time interval

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a postgres db, is it possible to backup data from this table for a time period(say 10:AM - 12:AM) and use the backup in similar postgres database.

Comment: No, because PostgreSQL doesn't know the creation time of a row.

Comment: For [backing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854200/how-do-i-backup-my-postgresql-database-with-cron) I would suggest you use [cron table](https://crontab.guru/) to trigger e.g pg_dump